# Microsoft Cloud App Security (MCAS) Session Policy bypassed by App but it is applied on browser. "bypass session control"

Tags: windows, outlook, desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31yQd.png)

I added the test user and tried to access the outlook desktop application it allows you to login without MDCA Access policy blocking you, but when checked in Azure sign-in logs for the test user the Azure Conditional Access policy was not getting applied and hence our MDCA Access policy is not blocking the session.

Explained you that for the MDCA Access policy to work and block the user to access the desktop application, the session must first match the Azure Conditional Access policy from Azure portal.

I want to blocked the Outlook desktop application and other mail application.